# Can anyone please explain to me why i = 1 and not 0 after running todos.pop();

Tags: javascript

I'm learning 'Loops' in Javascript.

Can anyone please explain to me why i = 1 and not 0 after running todos.pop();

```
for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    todos.pop();
}
```

Comment: What's `todos`?

Comment: @RoboRobok I think `todos` might be an array that the for loop is using?

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 That's for sure, but we don't know how many elements there are to explain it.

Comment: I'd imagine it's because `todos` had one element in it prior to the loop.

Comment: Not sure what your confusion here.

Comment: Because for loop came for next iteration after returning todos.pop(), it incremented by 1.
So 0 became 1 after loop. better you learn for, while, do while loops

Answer (score 1):

1. `var i = 0` - means that on the first iteration, `i` will be `0`
2. `i < todos.length` - means that loop will continue until `i` will become more or equal to `todos.length`. For example, if you have 5 todos, then `todos.length` will be `5`. So, the loop will work for `i = 0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. But since `5` is not less than `5` - it will not run 6th iteration.
3. `i++` - means that `i` will be increased by one after each iteration. Iteration - is what you have in the body of the loop. `todos.pop()` in this case.

So, if you're getting `i = 1` after running this code, this means that you have 1 (or 2) item(s) in your `todos` array, and loop iterated exactly one time. Like so:

1. `i = 0`
2. Is `i < todos.length`? = Is `i < 1`? = Is `0 < 1`? - Yes, run loop body.
3. Running loop body (`todos.pop()`).
4. Run `i++`, now `i = 1`
5. Is `i < todos.length`? = Is `i < 0` (since you `pop`ed item from todos, lengths is zero now)? = Is `1 < 0`? - No, terminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`i` increments on each iteration. `todos.pop()` does not affect `i` but decrements `todos.length`.

Your loop will pop half of the elements in the array as each iteration `i` will increment but `todos.length` will decrement.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say todos has 1 element in it. This is what would happen

1. You initialise i as 0
2. You pop one off todos in the body of the function.
3. It increments your iterator i by 1 (i++)

At the end of one iteration of that loop, the value of i will be 1.

Here's the thing though, because your todos.length is changing as the loop is proceeding, the loop will behave in ways you might find odd.

Say your array has 2 elements in it (I'm guessing this is where your question actually comes in).

1. You initialise i to 0
2. You pop one off the todos
3. todos.length is now 1 and i is also 1
4. The loop stops because it is not less than todos.length any more